# Am i able to copy android native databases?

Tags: android, database, adb

I'm trying to copy android `mmssms.db` file to the SD card. And I'm facing some kind of permission issue.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db (Permission denied)

Is there a way to force or bypass that? Because I tried with success to copy/paste these files from Eclipse DDMS File explorer. And see that it's possible from the `adb pull/push` command to make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect it to work? This is not your application's DB, you shouldn't have an access to it. If something is not allowed from java code, it is not allowed from native code either.

When using ADB or DDMS, it is the user that access, not some specific application, and this is not the case when running from your application of course.

Comment: So, I would like to backup sms. I thought about content providers to access theses data, read and store that on files, or some other ways. But keeping in mind that I would also like to restore these data, doing the reverse job: reading specifics lines to restore data would be hard and rude.
Could I create empty databases files on my application, read android private database and just clone the exact structure and content?